# CakePHP custom query without own table

Tags: php, cakephp, pdo

I have a query which joins other tables and insert a custom row named `action` with static value `started`. At a later stage I will have to `UNION` 2 more querys which contains another static value in the row `custom`.

How do I implement this without having an own table for this values? Im used to `PDO` where I can make an array with my entrys and loop through. All i see in the documentation is where you have a fix table with these records.

```
select a.StartTimestamp, b.Name, b.LastName, 'Started' AS 'action', c.translation
from a
inner join b on a.ID = b.ID
inner join c on b.ID = c.ID
group by a.StartTimestamp
order by a.StartTimestamp DESC
limit 5;
```

Comment: Please always mention the CakePHP version that you are using (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!